# How do I take value of a string leading up to a comma using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to take the city out of a city, state string. For instance, "Portland, OR" would need to equal "Portland". How can I use Javascript or a regular expression to do this?

var myString = "Portland, OR";

I want to extract everything up to the comma but not including the comma.

Comment: You should provide sample input and desired output for each it would help a lot.

Comment: You might try a regular expression that matches everything from the start of a string that isn't a comma and returns it, or matches everything from the first comma to the end of the string and removes it.

Comment: Just use regex [`^[^,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/wn7A6y/4), this is a very simple question, next time use google...

Answer (score 2):

```
var city = "Portland, OR".split(",")[0];
```

With regex:

```
var regex = /^[^,]+/;
var city =  regex.exec("Portland, OR");
```

Comment: Works, not very efficient though.

Comment: The easyiest way in the provided string. In other case, regex can be the best.

Comment: @LucasCosta Give this examle with regex too) thanks

Comment: Edited with regex @pwnz22

Answer (score 2):

This is the regex version

```
var result = myString.match(/^[^,]+/)
```

**UPDATE**

This one always returns a value without error

```
var result = String(myString || "").match(/^[^,]*/)[0]
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using Regex over the split or substr methods?

Comment: in your case "no", for all other cases maybe

Comment: Splitting is easy to read, but will always be either as fast, or slower than any alternative. As such, regex or substring will always be better than splitting a string for this purpose.

Comment: That will return an array or null, perhaps `myString.match(/^[^,]+/) || [''])[0]` which will return the matched part or empty string if there is no match.

Comment: @RobG this one always returns non empty array except string is empty. I will update the answer for that case